# Office 365 API is returning incorrect start and end datetimes for all day events

Tags: json, api, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

Here's the steps to reproduce the bug:

1. Check your timezone settings in Office 365, mine is set to Eastern US, so it's a 5 hour offset right now: http://take.ms/2qwxJ
2. Create an all-day event: http://take.ms/tRWSf
3. Confirm that the event starts and ends on 12am - 12am in your timezone by viewing the event in week view and observing that it does not overlap into other days.  I have also confirmed they all day event is saved as expected by viewing it in a desktop outlook client that is synced with the office 365 account.  There, you can see that the timezone for the event is correct (EST).
4. view the event via the calendarview api endpoint.  Notice that it shows the timezone as UTC, and reports the start and end times as midnight to midnight UTC.

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2016-01-25T01:00:00Z&endDateTime=2016-02-01T23:00:00Z

```
{  
  "@odata.context":"https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/CalendarView",
  "value":[  
    {  
      "@odata.id":"NOT IMPORTANT",
      "@odata.etag":"NOT IMPORTANT",
      "Id":"NOT IMPORTANT",
      "DateTimeCreated":"2016-01-20T20:48:49.3867149Z",
      "DateTimeLastModified":"2016-01-20T20:48:49.4179638Z",
      "ChangeKey":"NOT IMPORTANT",
      "Categories":[  

      ],
      "StartTimeZone":"UTC",
      "EndTimeZone":"UTC",
      "ResponseStatus":{  
        "Response":"Organizer",
        "Time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "iCalUId":"NOT IMPORTANT",
      "Reminder":null,
      "HasAttachments":false,
      "Subject":"My all day event, in EST",
      "Body":{  
        "ContentType":"HTML",
        "Content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
      },
      "BodyPreview":"",
      "Importance":"Normal",
      "Sensitivity":"Normal",
      "Start":"2016-01-26T00:00:00Z",
      "End":"2016-01-27T00:00:00Z",
      "Location":{  
        "DisplayName":""
      },
      "IsAllDay":true,
      "IsCancelled":false,
      "IsOrganizer":true,
      "Recurrence":null,
      "ResponseRequested":true,
      "SeriesMasterId":null,
      "ShowAs":"Busy",
      "Type":"SingleInstance",
      "Attendees":[  

      ],
      "Organizer":{  
        "EmailAddress":{  
          "Name":"brett",
          "Address":"NOT IMPORTANT"
        }
      },
      "WebLink":"NOT IMPORTANT"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect the start and end times to be accurate to the start and end of the day in Eastern Standard Time

```
"Start":"2016-01-26T05:00:00Z",
"End":"2016-01-27T05:00:00Z",
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily fetch data from v1 API too, 
you just need to insure that on time of asking for time you are passing `UTC` timezone and for fetching information you need to specify for which timezone you are expecting.

```
        $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
        $deviceTimeStart = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
        $deviceTimeEndPlus1 = $date->modify('+1 minutes');
        $deviceTimeEnd = $deviceTimeEndPlus1->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');


            $httpHeader = array(
                "authorization: Bearer *****access_token*****",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "Prefer : outlook.timezone = \"Asia/Kolkata\""
            );

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime='.$TimeStart.'&endDateTime='.$TimeEnd.'&$select=Subject,Organizer,Start,End,bodyPreview,changeKey,location,attendees,organizer,lastModifiedDateTime',
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $httpHeader,
                )
            );
            $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $responseNew = (array) json_decode($curlResponse, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

All day events are midnight-to-midnight in any time zone. UTC is not any different.

Comment: But this event is in EST, so it should be: starting and ending at 5am UTC

Comment: We can discuss what it *should* do, but that hardly matters - it does what it does and you have to live with that (unless you can convince Microsoft to change the API behavior in all future versions and patch the old versions). I simply gave you the reasoning behind their decision to return the data in UTC.

Comment: Just to chime in, Dmitry is correct that this is by design. The thinking here is that usually when someone creates an "all-day" event, they don't *really* mean that the event has a hard start at midnight and hard stop at the following midnight. It's just something that happens "all day". So the times themselves aren't that important, it's really about the dates.

Comment: @JasonJohnston - Thanks for the response - The problem is that I need to know when this user is available / unavailable.  The api is neither giving me an exact time, OR a correct timezone based on their settings.  How can I determine when he/she is available?  - I would agree that just dates are fine, IF I am also given the timezone that the user has set for their meetings / calendar.

Comment: The v2.0 API does return `OriginalStartTimeZone` and `OriginalEndTimeZone` on each event, indicating the time zone it was created in. However, for all day, that is always set to `UTC`. The intent of these is that the start and end should act as a floating time (in RFC 2445 terms). I get that makes it difficult to use in availability calculations though. To match the intent of the event, you should interpret it as midnight in the time zone of the client checking the availability.

Comment: Ugh, very poor design choice, IMO.  If the time is not important for all day events, do what Google does: only provide dates.  By providing the time, I'm expecting that the time matters, which is misleading.

Comment: Here 6 years later to be confused by this answer. The timezone is very much relevant for all day events. If a user in UTC+8 creates an all day event when it's February 1st in local time, but still evening of January 31th in Greenwich, what will the timestamps of the event be - `2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z - 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z` or `2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z - 2022-02-02T00:00:00.000Z`? The logical choice would be if it's `2022-02-01T00:00:00.000+08:00`, or, as @CaptainHypertext suggests, do as Google and only provide dates, but in the _local timezone_.